# unable to display spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

This is my spinner in xml

```
  <Spinner
     android:id="@+id/product_details_spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_3"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl_3"
     android:layout_below="@+id/rl_3"
     />
```

and this is my java code

```
List<String > sizelist = new ArrayList<String >();
spinner = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.product_details_spinner);


            sizelist.add("Select Size");
            sizelist.add("small");
            sizelist.add("medium");
            sizelist.add("large");

            ArrayAdapter<String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sizelist);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I dont know why I am unable to display a simple spinner. I can view it in design but when I run on device spinner is not displayed.

Please help!

**Edit:** I tried using string array in xml its working but I need to give the array from java as this will be dynamic

```
<string-array name="items">
        <item>Item 1</item>
        <item>Item 2</item>
        <item>Item 3</item>
        <item>Item 4</item>
        <item>Item 5</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: sizelist.add("Select Size");
            sizelist.add("small");
            sizelist.add("medium");
            sizelist.add("large"); its written in code

Comment: Are you getting any error while running the app?

Comment: Nope. not getting any error

Comment: Can you see other stuffs on the screen where spinner should be? Like other views if you have any. Are they visible?

Comment: yes all views are visible except spinner

Comment: Why are you using `alignRight`, `alignLeft`, `layout_below` for the same id `rl_3` ?

Comment: so that the left and right boundries are aligned for both the views and spinner is below rl_3 layout

Comment: try to change color of text black/white

Comment: You are setting spinner width as wrap_content, so its size become small and also its background color is also white. so it is not displaying. Please apply background color for spinner and try again. android:background="#888888"

Comment: remove all the dependencies first i.e. remove : android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_3"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl_3"
android:layout_below="@+id/rl_3" and then run and check if spinner is visible, if yes then the dependencies are shrinking the Spinner

Comment: I tried background color black --not working and its width is also not small as i have applied left and right alignment to its above view which has sufficient width

Comment: Are you sure it's visible on preview pane ??

Comment: Do what @mithil1501 mentioned above( you are setting align left,right and below are same id) remove any 2 alignment or change the ids. If it is not working, try to set theme for that spinner " android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" ". I am not sure this will fix this problem

Comment: I did that no success and when I give string array in xml its working. but when I set adapter in java its not working

Comment: try calling 'notifyDataSetChanged()' on adapter after 'spinner.setAdapter(adapter);'

Answer (score 0):

you set `    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/rl_3"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/rl_3" you are setting both so it is not working, you use only one 
and aslo do it

```
            ArrayAdapter<String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String >(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,sizelist);
```

Comment: I was using ArrayAdapter<String > before but ide suggested me to remove  that . I again added that an not working  I also removed the alignment no luck

Answer (score 0):

I became really silly while testing your code, What happened was The spinner was behind the `Navigation` bar when I tested your code in new Project.

[image: Spinner behind nav]

Only after adding these attribute It became visible and everything worked fine

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/product_details_spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />
```

May be you are facing the same, Have a look and be sure Your `Spinner` is visible at preview pane.

Comment: no my spinner is below certain views and its visible in preview pannel